# Fish and org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, shell

I am having troubles with the output of a fish session in org-babel. It seems to be related to the bracketed paste, but only happens when :session is used. I was wondering if there is any way to clean up the repeated lines produced within the shell session associated (its contents are below). I searched all over the internet but documentation exists for each component (org-babel session, fish and bracketed paste), but not for their usage in tandem. If anyone has a clue of why could org-babel be failing to filter-out all lines that would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just to add a bit of context, I am using doom-emacs, but that does not seem to be related to the problem.

```
#+begin_src shell
echo "tmp"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: tmp

#+begin_src shell :session var :results output raw
set VAR "tmp"
echo $VAR
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
set VAR 
$ set VAR "tmp"
$ set VAR "tmp"
echo
echo $VAR
$ echo $VAR
[?2004ltmp
echo
```

Shell session buffer:

```
$ set VAR "tmp"
$ echo $VAR
tmp
$ echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
org_babel_sh_eoe
```

Comment: If it works on its own (outside of `org-babel`) then I would guess that the matching of the prompt that allows `org-babel` to figure out what is a prompt and what is a command, is failing. Please report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. EDIT: I can reproduce it too. It's almost certainly a bug.

Comment: BTW, what "bracketed paste" are you talking about?

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and it has to do with the dumb terminal printing the input twice. It does not seem related to [bracketed paste](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste) in the end, but there is the link in case that it is useful. I will report the bug. In the meantime, I just silence the output of executing cells and use the inferior prompt manually, thanks anyways!

Comment: Thanks for the link! TIL...

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the language as `fish`, rather than `shell`. Also, check if fish is supported by babel by checking the value of the variable `org-babel-shell-names`.

Comment: This is probably not an answer (it could be a comment), but it  *is* useful: specifying `fish` as the language changes the output to nothing in my experiment. That's still wrong but it is different, so it might provide an additional clue. `fish` has been included in `org-babel-shell-names` since Dec. 2018 (AFAICT - it was added in version 9.2), so that is unlikely to be a problem. In any case, I still can reproduce the problem even on latest.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this persists for shell, bash and fish.